# CONFIG_MMC_ATMELMCI...no devices detected

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, sd-card, atmel

I'm trying to compile a kernel for a GESBC-9G20w from Glomation.  The board is built around a AT91SAM9G20.  My problem is that I can't detect an sd card with my kernel.  The demo kernel they provide works, so I know the hardware's good, but I need a newer kernel version.

I can provide lot's more info, but I tried only provide the important stuff for starters.

I'm using kernel source from https://github.com/linux4sam/linux-at91

Kernel config options...

```
#
# AT91SAM9G20 Board Type
#
CONFIG_MACH_AT91SAM9G20EK=y
CONFIG_MACH_AT91SAM9G20EK_2MMC=y
CONFIG_MACH_CPU9G20=y
CONFIG_MACH_ACMENETUSFOXG20=y
CONFIG_MACH_PORTUXG20=y
CONFIG_MACH_STAMP9G20=y
CONFIG_MACH_PCONTROL_G20=y
CONFIG_MACH_GSIA18S=y
CONFIG_MACH_SNAPPER_9260=y
```

```
CONFIG_MMC=y
# CONFIG_MMC_DEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_MMC_UNSAFE_RESUME is not set
# CONFIG_MMC_CLKGATE is not set

#
# MMC/SD/SDIO Card Drivers
#
CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK=y
CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK_MINORS=8
CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK_BOUNCE=y
# CONFIG_SDIO_UART is not set
# CONFIG_MMC_TEST is not set

#
# MMC/SD/SDIO Host Controller Drivers
#
# CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI is not set
# CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_PXAV3 is not set
# CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_PXAV2 is not set
# CONFIG_MMC_AT91 is not set
CONFIG_MMC_ATMELMCI=y
# CONFIG_MMC_SPI is not set
# CONFIG_MMC_DW is not set
# CONFIG_MMC_VUB300 is not set
# CONFIG_MMC_USHC is not set
# CONFIG_MEMSTICK is not set
CONFIG_NEW_LEDS=y
CONFIG_LEDS_CLASS=y
```

Boot log...

```
NET: Registered protocol family 17
input: gpio-keys as /devices/platform/gpio-keys/input/input0
rtc-at91sam9 rtc-at91sam9.0: setting system clock to 1970-01-01 00:16:52 UTC (1012)
atmel_mci atmel_mci: version: 0x210
atmel_mci atmel_mci: no DMA channel available
atmel_mci atmel_mci: using PDC
atmel_mci atmel_mci: Atmel MCI controller at 0xfffa8000 irq 25, 2 slots
ALSA device list:
  No soundcards found.
Waiting 5sec before mounting root device...
usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using at91_ohci
usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using at91_ohci
usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi0 : usb-storage 1-2:1.0
scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     2.0      2.0              5.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 7968768 512-byte logical blocks: (4.08 GB/3.79 GiB)
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page present
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page present
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
 sda: sda1
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page present
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
EXT4-fs (sda1): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) on device 8:1.
devtmpfs: mounted
Freeing unused kernel memory: 152K (c03ee000 - c0414000)
```

...but when I look in /dev, there are no mmcblk devices.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi did you ever sort this out? thanks

Comment: Well, sort of... Glomation support told me I had to use an older kernel so by trial and error I found that I could use mainline kernel 3.6.11 so that I could use the SD card and I manually copied in the wifi driver from 3.12,17.